# Change tab on button click without update tabView

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabview

I want to change a tab by clicking in commandButton. I'm controlling activeIndex on my bean and doing an update on tabView component. Everything works fine.

My problem is that I want to change the activeIndex without need doing an update on tabView, because update of that component is a bit slow.

Is it possible to change a tab by clicking on button, and do that without update?

Here is my actual code.

**TabView component**

```
 <p:tabView id="tvFoo" dynamic="true" activeIndex="#{fooBean.activeIndex}">


       <p:tab title="Title" id="someTab">                                         
          <ui:include src="someTabName.xhtml" />          
       </p:tab>

       <p:tab title="Title2" id="anotherTab">                                         
          <ui:include src="anotherTabName.xhtml" />       
       </p:tab>

</tabView>
```

**inside someTabName.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="go to anotherTab"  actionListener="#{fooBean.tabChange('anotherTabName')}" />
```

**fooBean, that controls tabs change**

```
public void tabChange(String tabId) {    
        switch (tabId) {    
        case "anotherTabName":                                      
            activeIndex = 2;
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tvFoo"); //here is the line that I don't want to call                    
        break;
    }
```

Can I remove that line, `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tvFoo");`? Of course, if simply remove, the tab is not changed.

To resume, basically I want change the opened tab. I think that I can achieve this calling the changeTab event manually, but I don't know how do that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do an update on the tabview component by your command button?
I think you have to do an update somewhere, otherwise, how should the tabview notice the change? Moreover, as far as I know, the update function isn't slow at all.

To get the current index of the tabview you could play with the Faces Context:

```
TabView tabView = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(aComponentId);
```

On `tabView` you can get and set the active tab individually.

I hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your time. The problem with doing an update is that there some 'heavy' tabs on that component, and doing an update on whole component just for change a tab seems a bit strange, right? Can I do an update that doesn't reload all tabs?

Comment: You are able to set an id on every component you want to query it directly - same for the `<p:tab>` item. That means, that you can do an update in a commandbutton like `<p:tab id="tabId" ... /> ...<p:commandButton update="tabId"` and it will refresh only the named tab.

Comment: I'm trying to update only the tab, by ID. But nothing happens, the tab change to index 2 only when I update the entire tabView.

Comment: Do you have a static oder dynamic number of tabs?

Comment: Yes, it's static numbers

Comment: I don't know if you noticed that my command button is not in the tab that I want to change, my button is in tab A, when I click I want to move to tab B

Comment: You **cannot** update individual tabs in PrimeFaces that way. Where did you read/learn that

Comment: @Kukeltje well, in fact I don't want to update the tab, I just want to open it. It's seems a simple thing, I want to do the same as an wizard do, but without a wizard

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the wizard component? I believe the behaviour you're looking for is similar to this primefaces wizard.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/wizard.xhtml

Comment: sorry, wizard is not what I want.